# IPTABLES blocking port 25 even though it's enabled

Tags: iptables, centos-7

I'm using centos7 and have the following rules set up:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [6:394]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [42:6917]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 433 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

But for some reason port 25 isn't working when I try to send emails.  If I disable iptables all is fine, so I know it has something to do with that.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If this is a home network, it is probably your ISP dropping the traffic to prevent you from running a mail server. Most residential ISPs do this.

Comment: Doesn't this line pretty much drop anything: `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP`

Comment: supposed to drop erroneous and unspecified traffic.  And this is in a data center.

Comment: For a data center, you should really ask this question on [sf].

Comment: This isn't about a datacenter, this is about a program commonly found in most linux os distros.  This isn't the place to ask a question related to "super user" issues?

Comment: try  iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp m tcp --dport 25 -J ACCEPT